GitHub GraphQL API Issue: Wrong Cursor Error When Querying for ISSUE Data
I was querying GitHub data using the GraphQL Explorer in my code, and suddenly encountered a 'wrong cursor' error when attempting to retrieve ISSUE data. Upon testing the same query in the GitHub Explorer, I noticed that the API response had changed. Has anyone else encountered this issue?
I have a personal project which fetches data from github public repos.
